# Error in JSON when I am doing a AJAX call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm getting the following error in the console when I am trying to return a string of JSON from a AJAX call.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I have added a codepen with the code I am using.

If you click the convert button and look in the console you will see the error.

I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks.

JB

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJvyWq

```
jQuery('.convert').click(function(){
    jQuery.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback=?", function(data){
        console.log("Data: " + data);
    }, 'json')
});
```

Comment: You dont need to add `’json’` at the end of the get request.

Comment: If I don't I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.responsive.sportsgirl.com.au' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Here is the codepen link `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJvyWq`

Answer (score 2):

First remove  the "=" .

for a string display in the console you can use the methode   stringify of the JSON object

```
jQuery('.convert').click(function(){


jQuery.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback", function(data){
         console.log("Data: " +JSON.stringify(data) );
            }, 'json');
        });
```

or for display an object in the console you can juste  write :

jQuery('.convert').click(function(){

```
jQuery.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback", function(data){
         console.log(data );
            }, 'json');
        });
```

the result  :

```
Object {To: "CAD", From: "EUR", Rate: "1.3138"}
```

Comment: `console.log("Data: " +data );` would output `Data: [object Object]`. What exactly does removing `?` do?

Comment: remove the "=" which generate the error ,i correct it ,sorry for the wrong and for the console.log(data) without "Data"  it will  generate   Object {To: "CAD", From: "EUR", Rate: "1.3138"}

Comment: we can remove also &callback because it unusefull in this case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the callback=? from the end of the URL you are providing OR remove the 'json' from the .get() method call.

```
jQuery('.convert').click(function(){
  jQuery.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD", function(data){
        console.log(data);
  });});
```

This is because jQuery assumes that when you pass a "callback" parameter in URL and type 'json' that the response will be [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about). But in this case the server sends a JSON string. Instead of passing "?" if you pass the name of an existing function the error will not be thrown.

The current response by the server is:

```
{"To":"CAD","From":"EUR","Rate":"1.3138"}
```

If the Server was responding with JSONP and if the callback you passed was "test" then the response would have been:

```
test({"To":"CAD","From":"EUR","Rate":"1.3138"})
```

http://codepen.io/tejzpr/pen/yymQNz?editors=101 explains both cases.

Comment: I think it would more helpful if you explained why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `json` at the second parameter as @SnehalShah said and it'll work

```
$('.convert').click(function(){
    $.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback=?", function(data){
         console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));  
    });
});
```

Comment: You should explain why mate, not just post code answers.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/1z20m3pL/

Try this way::

```
jQuery('.convert').click(function(){
    jQuery.get("https://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=EUR&to=CAD&callback=?", function(data){
                    console.log("To: " + data.To);
                    console.log("From: " + data.From);
                    console.log("Rate: " + data.Rate);
                });
            });
```